# How can I get working directory content as it was at specific commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a git repository with some commits in it. I want to reproduce **exact** state of working directory as it was right after specific commit (Here i suppose that i've commited all changes that were made).

I tried to use `git checkout`, but this command doesn't delete existing files (which were added after desired commit) in working directory.

Simple example to illustrate my problem. I prepared repository using following commands

```
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git/.git/

u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ echo 'ffff' > first.file
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git add first.file
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git commit -m "Important file was added"
[master (root-commit) fb05f7e] Important file was added
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 first.file

u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ echo 'Second line' >> first.file 
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git commit -m "Important data was added" -a
[master df93d04] Important data was added
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ echo 'ssss' > second.file
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git add second.file
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git commit -m "Second important file was added"
[master b6c106a] Second important file was added
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 second.file

u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ echo 'tttt' > third.file
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git add third.file
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git commit -m "Third important file was added"
[master 33fce06] Third important file was added
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 third.file
```

Right now directory looks like this

```
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ ls
first.file  second.file  third.file
```

`first.file` has following content

```
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ cat first.file 
ffff
Second line
```

Now i want restore working directory as it looked right after first commit (`fb05f7e`)

```
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ git checkout fb05f7e .
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ cat first.file 
ffff
```

But `second.file` and `third.file` are still in the directory

```
u@u-desktop:/tmp/git$ ls
first.file  second.file  third.file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.` in your `git checkout`. Selections from the man page:

```
   git checkout [<branch>], git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start
     point>], git checkout [--detach] [<commit>]
       This form switches branches by updating the index, working tree,
       and HEAD to reflect the specified branch or commit.

       (...)

   git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...
       When <paths> or --patch are given, git checkout does not switch
       branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the
       index file or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit).
```

If, moreover you want to remove files that are *not* checked in the index, use `git clean` (read the man page, there's an "anti-oops" option you'll have to pass on the command line for it to work).

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
git checkout fb05f7e
```

... i.e. *without* specifying the current directory (`.`) as the path to checkout.  You'll find that `second.file` and `third.file` are removed as you expect.

The reason for this is that `git checkout` has two very different modes of operation, depending on whether you supply a path or not.  If you do supply a path it doesn't change `HEAD` at all, it just

> ... updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file, or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit)

(That's from the [`git checkout` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)).  This only updates the paths that were actually present in that other commit.